# How do I build a static libvlc under CentOS7?

Tags: build, centos, vlc, libvlc

I have a program written by PyQt that plays video by binding libvlc.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import os
import vlc

from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *

class vlc_demo(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(vlc_demo, self).__init__()
        self.__ui__()
        self.__load__()

    def __ui__(self):

        self.setFixedSize(800,600)
        t_lay_parent = QVBoxLayout()
        self.m_label_media = QLabel()
        t_lay_bottom = QHBoxLayout()
        self.m_button_one = QPushButton("one")
        self.m_button_too = QPushButton("too")
        self.m_button_three = QPushButton("three")
        t_lay_bottom.addWidget(self.m_button_one)
        t_lay_bottom.addWidget(self.m_button_too)
        t_lay_bottom.addWidget(self.m_button_three)

        self.m_button_one.clicked.connect(self.slt_one)
        self.m_button_too.clicked.connect(self.slt_too)
        self.m_button_three.clicked.connect(self.slt_three)

        t_lay_parent.addWidget(self.m_label_media)
        t_lay_parent.addLayout(t_lay_bottom)
        self.setLayout(t_lay_parent)

    def __load__(self):
        self.m_instance = vlc.Instance()
        self.m_player = self.m_instance.media_player_new()
        self.m_win_id = self.m_label_media.winId()
        if sys.platform.startswith('linux'):  # linux
            self.m_player.set_xwindow(self.m_win_id)
        elif sys.platform == "win32":  # windows
            self.m_player.set_hwnd(self.m_win_id)
        elif sys.platform == "darwin":  # mac
            self.m_player.set_nsobject(self.m_win_id)

    def slt_one(self):
        self.m_label_media.show()
        media = self.m_instance.media_new("1.mp4")
        self.m_player.set_media(media)
        self.m_player.play()

    def slt_too(self):
        self.m_label_media.show()
        media = self.m_instance.media_new("2.mp4")
        self.m_player.set_media(media)
        self.m_player.play()

    def slt_three(self):
        self.m_label_media.hide()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = vlc_demo()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Under windows, copy the following files and directories in the VLC media player directory. The program can run on the machine without VLC media player.

```
 - libvlc.dll
 - libvlccore.dll
 - plugins
```

Under CentOS7, is there any way to run the program without installing VLC media player?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you may use Snapcraft Parts which AFAIU is designed for just that.

For VLC that's https://github.com/videolan/vlc/blob/master/extras/package/snap/snapcraft.yaml

Comment: Thank you very much. It's very useful to me